# rock, paper, scissor-python-code. help simplify

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I've only written a couple programs. Here's a recent code I wrote for a **rock-paper-scissors** game. I've already tested it and it works great. Is there any way I can simplify it? Thanks!

```
import random

wins=0   
losses=0    
ties=0    
rounds=0

r=1 #rock    
p=2 #paper    
s=3 #scissors

y = "The computer has made its choice, how about you?"

while rounds <= 10:    
 print y    
 x = input('(1)rock, (2)paper, or (3)scissors? :')
 choice = x    
 cpu_choice= random.randint(1, 3)

if (choice, cpu_choice) == (1, 2):    
  rounds += 1    
  losses += 1    
  print 'computer chose paper, you lose'
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (3, 2):    
  print 'you win'    
  rounds += 1    
  wins += 1    
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (2, 2):    
  print 'TIE!'    
  rounds += 1    
  ties += 1    
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (1, 3):    
  print 'you win'    
  rounds += 1    
  wins += 1    
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (3, 3):   
  print 'TIE!'    
  rounds += 1    
  ties += 1    
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (2, 3):    
  print 'computer chose scissors, you lose'    
  rounds += 1    
  losses += 1    
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (1, 1):    
  print 'TIE'    
  rounds += 1    
  ties += 1    
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (3, 1):    
  print 'computer chose rock, you lose'    
  rounds += 1    
  losses += 1    
elif (choice, cpu_choice) == (2, 1):    
  print 'you win'    
  rounds += 1    
  wins += 1    
else:    
  print 'Please choose 1, 2, or 3'

print 'Game Over'

if wins>losses:
  print 'YOU WON'    
  print 'wins:' , wins   
  print 'losses' , losses    
  print 'ties' , ties    
else:    
 print 'you lose'    
 print 'wins:' , wins    
 print 'losses:' , losses    
 print 'ties:' , ties
```

Comment: "The computer has made its choice, how about you?" -- it hasn't at the time you print the message ;)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is made for questions like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While stackoverflow is not really meant as a learning platform, here are some advises:

- Read the ZEN (type `import this` into your python console).
- In your particular case, plenty of conditions are usually a bad idea.

At the very least, all TIE conditions can be thrown together:

```
 if choice == cpu_choice:
    # TIE
```

Throw in some grammar:

```
names = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
print("Computer chooses {}, you loose".format(names[cpu_choice]))
```

Essentially, there are only three conditions:

```
wins, losses = 0, 0

for round in range(10):

    # Your choice and CPU choice

    cpu_wins = (cpu_choice > choice or (choice == 3 and cpu_choice == 1))
    tie = (cpu_choice == choice)

    if cpu_wins:
        # You loose
        print("Computer chooses {}, you loose".format(names[cpu_choice]))
        losses += 1
    if not cpu_wins and tie:
        # tie
    else:
        # you win
```

Also, you don't even use the variables `p`, `r` and `s` defined above....

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

1. All your conditional cases contain round variable increasing, except when wrong data input occured, so you can bring **round += 1** lines out upper, and decrrease round variable only once in else case
2. You have if cases that do same jobs, e.g. when 'TIE!' happened; it's better to group such cases. 'TIE!' cases can be grouped under one condition **choice == cpu_choice** thus ommiting 3 elif clauses. Think about the same problem in other game cases.
3. Use better code formatting, e.g. what [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standard suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine whether the player wins using modulo arithmetic:

```
player_result = ["tie", "win", "lose"]
player_choice = input('(1)rock, (2)paper, or (3)scissors? :')
cpu_choice= random.randint(1, 3)
result = player_result[(player_choice - cpu_choice) % 3]

print "You " + result
if result == "win":
    wins += 1
elif result == "lose":
    loses += 1
```

Comment: I'd prefer `(player_choice - cpu_choice) % 3`.  I don't (want to) remember how tightly the mod operator `%` binds in python, so better play it safe.

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat yourself:

- `rounds += 1` happens in every round so you don't have to put in every branch
- printing the result numbers happens always, too.
- Indent your code using four spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, which may be a bit above your level, but If you research how this code works, you will be much better at pythoN! :)

```
from random import randint

def do_rounds(num_rounds):
    choice_dict = {1: 'rock', 2: 'paper', 3: 'scissors'}
    beats_dict = {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 2}

    for round in range(num_rounds):
        computer_choice = randint(1, 3)
        while True:
            player_choice = raw_input('(1)rock, (2)paper, or (3)scissors? :')
            if player_choice in ("1", "2", "3"):
                player_choice = int(player_choice)
                break
            else:
                print "input must be an integer 1, 2 or 3"

        player_lost = beats_dict[computer_choice] == player_choice

        tie = 1 if computer_choice == player_choice else 0
        win = 0 if player_lost else 1
        loss = 1 if player_lost else 0
        print "computer picked: %s" % choice_dict[computer_choice],
        print " you picked: %s" % choice_dict[player_choice]
        yield tie, win, loss

def run_game():
    ties, wins, losses = zip(*do_rounds(4))
    ties, wins, losses = sum(ties), sum(wins), sum(losses)
    print "ties = %s, wins = %s, losses = %s" % (ties, wins, losses)
    if wins > losses:
        print "you won!"
    elif wins == losses:
        print "tie!"
    else:
        print "loser!!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_game()

"""
(1)rock, (2)paper, or (3)scissors? :3
computer picked: rock, you picked: scissors
(1)rock, (2)paper, or (3)scissors? :2
computer picked: paper, you picked: paper
(1)rock, (2)paper, or (3)scissors? :1
computer picked: paper, you picked: rock
(1)rock, (2)paper, or (3)scissors? :3
computer picked: rock, you picked: scissors
ties = 1, wins = 1, losses = 3
loser!!!
"""
```

Comment: Your `assert` statement does not do quite what you think it does. If your python script is run with the optimized (`-O`) command line option, all `assert` statements are silently skipped. So it is meant as a [debugging tool](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement), not as a replacement for `if` + `raise`.

Comment: Yup - It's not ready for production yet. If so I would print out the appropriate message to the user and ask for another input.

Comment: Why not just wrap the user input function in a `while player_choice not in "123"` instead? Also, `input` *evaluates* what the player types as python source code. This is normally not desired behaviour, and could be or become a security hole. Use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: @lazyr your edit introduced a bug of if the input is 12 for example, it will accept the input!

Comment: Huh, now why didn't I think of that. Well spotted!